ChangeLogParseException When Using Relative Path Traversal (../) in Include Statements After Upgrading to Liquibase 4.24
After upgrading from Liquibase version 3.x to 4.24, I encountered a ChangeLogParseException related to resolving relative paths in  statements that utilize directory traversal (../). This issue arises when attempting to include changelog files located outside the immediate directory structure, especially when some changelogs are packaged within JARs.
Changelog A(main changelog)
    <include file="config/liquibase/B.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false" />

Above liquibase file B.xml is present in a jar dependency of my project with structure:
config/liquibase
        └──-|---releases/1.1.3/
                   ├── core/
                   │   └── D.xml
                   ├── master/
                   │   └── C.xml
         ── B.xml  (Packaged inside a JAR)

B has:
    <includeAll path="releases/1.1.3/master" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="1.1.3"/>

C has:
    <include file="../core/D.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

Running Liquibase update command results in the following error:
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: The file config/liquibase/releases/1.1.3/master/../core/D.xml was not found in the configured search path.
If the  path in C.xml is changed to <include file="core/D.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/> and the D.xml is moved accordingly, Liquibase processes the changelogs without errors.
Is using a relative path with folder traversal not supported? A relative path like "../core/D.xml" in a include statement?
